# Convex constraint function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I would like to ask a question about the convexity of the constraint functions.

We have constraints for an optimization problem:

$$x=x^+-x^-$$
$$y=y^+-y^-$$
$$x^+\geqslant A(y^+)^2$$
$$x^-\geqslant A(y^-)^2$$
$$(xx^+)^{0.5}\geqslant0$$
$$(-xx^-)^{0.5}\geqslant0$$

where $x,y$ are variables, $x^+,x^-,y^+,y^-$ are positive variables, and $A$ is a positive constant.

Are the constraint functions convex?

Thank you.

Dylan

Comment: What do you think? Some guess?

Comment: It is nonconvex since the last two constraint functions are convex only when the variables are strictly positive.

Comment: $\sqrt{ xx^+ }$ is real only if $x^+ \ge x^-$ anyway ...